# 134 posts awaiting review - where?

Tags: support, 10k-tools

I see 134 posts awaiting review, but not in any queue I have access to. I'm confused. Where are they?

[image: Screensot]

Comment: I realized it was a network-wide change, so posted here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230742/225745

Answer (score 4):

The number represents the [total number of items](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191638/notify-users-of-possible-reviews-on-toolbar/230726#comment757995_230726) in all of the review queues, and is only shown to 10k users.  The count is cached for all users, so it may or may not be precisely accurate at any given point in time.

Note that this number may be different the the number if items that you can review:

- It will include items you have already reviewed, but are still in the queue
- It will include items that you can't review (ie, you cast a vote on a post already)
- It will include items you have skipped, but are still in the queue
- It will include your own posts that are under review